# TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to dynamically change the content of my webpage whether a user is logged in or not, passing a user through req.locals. When i am trying to reach my homepage without logging in a user i take this error. If i logged in the user then i can reach my webpage

my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const mongoSanitize = require("express-mongo-sanitize");
const xss = require("xss-clean");
const hpp = require("hpp");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const viewRouter = require("./router/viewRoutes");
const userRouter = require("./router/userRoutes");
const reviewRouter = require("./router/reviewRoutes");
const productRouter = require("./router/productsRoutes");
const vrefikhFrontidaRouter = require("./router/vrefikhFrontidaRoutes")
const kavaRouter = require("./router/kavaRoutes")
const katoikidiaRouter = require("./router/katoikidiaRoutes")
const proswpikhFrontidaRouter = require("./router/proswpikhFrontidaRoutes")
const ugieinhDiatrofhRouter = require("./router/ugieinhDiatrofhRoutes")
const opwropwleioRouter = require("./router/opwropwleioRoutes")
const galaktokomikaEidhPsugeiouRouter = require("./router/galaktokomikaEidhPsugeiouRoutes")
const turiaAllantikaDelicatessenRouter = require("./router/turiaAllantikaDelicatessenRoutes")
const tupopoihmenaTrofhmaRouter = require("./router/tupopoihmenaTrofhmaRoutes")
const freskoKreasPsariRouter = require("./router/freskoKreasPsariRoutes")
const prwinoRofhmataRouter = require("./router/prwinoRofhmataRoutes")
const proiontaArtouRouter = require("./router/proiontaArtouRoutes")
const snacksRouter = require("./router/snacksRoutes")
const katharistikaXartikaEidhOikiakhsRouter = require("./router/katharistikaXartikaEidhOikiakhsRoutes")
const storeLocationRouter = require("./router/storeLocationRoutes");
const throwsAnError = require("./utils/throwsAnError");
const checkAuth = require('./middleware/check-auth');

const app = express();

if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test"){
    const limiter = rateLimit({
        max: 100,
        windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        message: "Too many request, please try again in an hour"
    });
    
    app.use("/api", limiter);
}

app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(helmet());
// For security reasons we accept body up to 10kb
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));
// Data sanitization (Cleaning the income data from malicious code)
// NoSQL data injection
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());

//Preventing HTTP parameter poloution
app.use(hpp());


// ROUTES

app.use("/", viewRouter);
app.use("/api/users", userRouter);
app.use("/api/review", reviewRouter);
app.use("/api/products", productRouter);
app.use("/api/products/vrefikh-frontida", vrefikhFrontidaRouter);
app.use("/api/products/kava", kavaRouter);
app.use("/api/products/katoikidia", katoikidiaRouter);
app.use("/api/products/proswpikh-frontida", proswpikhFrontidaRouter);
app.use("/api/products/diatrofh", ugieinhDiatrofhRouter);
app.use("/api/products/opwropwleio", opwropwleioRouter);
app.use("/api/products/galaktokomika-kai-eidh-psugeiou", galaktokomikaEidhPsugeiouRouter);
app.use("/api/products/turia-allantika-delicatessen", turiaAllantikaDelicatessenRouter);
app.use("/api/products/tupopoihmena-trofhma", tupopoihmenaTrofhmaRouter);
app.use("/api/products/fresko-kreas-kai-psari", freskoKreasPsariRouter);
app.use("/api/products/prwino-kai-rofhmata", prwinoRofhmataRouter);
app.use("/api/products/proionta-artou", proiontaArtouRouter);
app.use("/api/products/snacks", snacksRouter);
app.use("/api/products/katharistika-xartika-eidh-oikiakhs", katharistikaXartikaEidhOikiakhsRouter);
app.use("/api/stores", storeLocationRouter);

// Error handler for routes that do not exist
app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    // res.status(404).send({
    //     message: "The page you are looking for does not exist"
    // });
    const error = new throwsAnError("The page you are looking for does not exist", 404);
    next(error);
});

// Express' error handler middleware
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.statusCode).json({
        status: error.status,
        message: error.message,
        e: error.e.message ? error.e.message : ""
    })
    
});

module.exports = app;
```

my middleware that checks whether a user is logged in or not

```
exports.isLoggedIn = async function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies.jwt) {
        try {
          // 1) verify token
          const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(
            req.cookies.jwt,
            "thisismysecretpowerful@ndr@ndomp@ssaword"
          );
    
          // 2) Check if user still exists
          const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
          if (!currentUser) {
            return next();
          }
    
          // THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER
          res.locals.user = currentUser;
          return next();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          return next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

my homepage.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <%- include("includes/sideNavBar.ejs") %>
        <nav>
            <div class="bar-container" onclick="openNav()">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="user">
                <% if(user) { %>
                    <a href="signup">Εγγραφή</a>
                    <a href="login">Σύνδεση</a> 
                <% } else { %>
                    <a href="#"><%= user.userName %></a>
                    <a href="logout">Αποσύνδεση</a>
                <% } %>
                
            </div>
        </nav>
        <h1>Σύγκρινε τιμές σε περισσότερα απο 20000 προιόντα supermarket</h1>
        <div id="nameFlexContainer">
            <h2>mygrocery</h2> 
            <svg id="Icons" height="30" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="256" cy="256" fill="#f1f1f1" r="256"/><path d="m511.69 268.82c-6.69 135.43-118.61 243.18-255.69 243.18-135.19 0-245.91-104.8-255.34-237.58 17.36-17.11 27-42.78 47.86-56 22.4-14.23 55.17-8.69 71.65 12.1 11.2 14.12 15 33.21 27 46.64 13.32 14.88 36.35 20.09 54.78 12.39 7.31-3.05 14-7.93 21.81-9.23 11.81-2 23.54 4.61 35.5 4 14.57-.7 26.48-11.74 35.41-23.28s16.7-24.58 29-32.5c21.18-13.68 50.47-7.73 70.62 7.42 14.89 11.18 27 27.14 44.72 32.78 23.17 7.43 49.46-5.13 72.68.08z" fill="#f1f1f1"/><path d="m183.6 407.88a25.16 25.16 0 0 1 -47.54 11.51 24.9 24.9 0 0 1 -2.79-11.51 25.17 25.17 0 0 1 25.16-25.16 25.18 25.18 0 0 1 25.17 25.16z" fill="#334353"/><path d="m172.73 397a25.17 25.17 0 0 1 -25.17 25.17 24.89 24.89 0 0 1 -11.5-2.79 24.9 24.9 0 0 1 -2.79-11.51 25.17 25.17 0 0 1 25.16-25.16 24.9 24.9 0 0 1 11.51 2.79 24.86 24.86 0 0 1 2.79 11.5z" fill="#3e4e60"/><path d="m167.22 414.91a10.53 10.53 0 0 1 -7.42 3.09 10.46 10.46 0 0 1 -7.42-3.07l-32.19-32.19h38.24l10.62 19.81a10.51 10.51 0 0 1 -1.83 12.36z" fill="#c2aacf"/><path d="m164.16 417a10.35 10.35 0 0 1 -4.36 1 10.46 10.46 0 0 1 -7.42-3.07l-27-27h27.88l10.62 19.81a10.48 10.48 0 0 1 .28 9.26z" fill="#decee5"/><path d="m325.53 407.88a25.16 25.16 0 0 1 -47.53 11.51 24.9 24.9 0 0 1 -2.79-11.51 25.17 25.17 0 0 1 25.16-25.16 25.18 25.18 0 0 1 25.17 25.16z" fill="#334353"/><path d="m314.66 397a25.17 25.17 0 0 1 -25.17 25.17 24.89 24.89 0 0 1 -11.5-2.79 24.9 24.9 0 0 1 -2.79-11.51 25.17 25.17 0 0 1 25.16-25.16 24.9 24.9 0 0 1 11.51 2.79 24.86 24.86 0 0 1 2.79 11.5z" fill="#3e4e60"/><path d="m309.15 414.91a10.53 10.53 0 0 1 -7.42 3.07 10.46 10.46 0 0 1 -7.42-3.07l-32.19-32.19h38.24l10.64 19.81a10.51 10.51 0 0 1 -1.85 12.38z" fill="#c2aacf"/><path d="m306.09 417a10.35 10.35 0 0 1 -4.36 1 10.46 10.46 0 0 1 -7.42-3.07l-27-27h27.88l10.62 19.81a10.48 10.48 0 0 1 .28 9.26z" fill="#decee5"/><path d="m122.6 165.65a37 37 0 0 0 -37 37v87a36.82 36.82 0 0 0 6.31 20.65 37 37 0 0 0 30.65 16.31h221.22l43.11-160.89zm-12 123.92v-31h38.12v43h-26.12a12 12 0 0 1 -11.83-10.14 12.32 12.32 0 0 1 -.14-1.86zm63.12-31h40.12v43h-40.09zm65.12 0h40.16v43h-40.13zm65.11 43v-43h32.13l-11.51 43zm38.82-68h-38.77v-42.92h50.33zm-63.82 0h-40.08v-42.92h40.13zm-65.11 0h-40.09v-42.92h40.12zm-65.12 0h-38.09v-31a12 12 0 0 1 12-12h26.15z" fill="#c2aacf"/><path d="m122.6 165.65a37 37 0 0 0 -37 37v87a36.82 36.82 0 0 0 6.31 20.65 36.79 36.79 0 0 0 20.65 6.31h221.22l40.43-150.89zm-22 135.89v-53h48.12v53h-48.09zm0-68v-41a12 12 0 0 1 12-12h36.15v52.94h-48.12zm113.24 25v43h-50.09v-53h50.12zm0-67.94v42.94h-50.09v-52.89h50.12zm65.16 67.99v43h-50.13v-53h50.13zm0-67.94v42.94h-50.13v-52.94h50.13zm57.13 67.94-11.51 43h-30.62v-53h44.81zm-42.13-25v-52.94h63l-2.68 10-11.52 42.94z" fill="#decee5"/><g fill="#f4e6f4"><ellipse cx="163.41" cy="173.15" rx="36.63" ry="7.5"/><ellipse cx="183.41" cy="238.79" rx="25.4" ry="5.2"/><ellipse cx="203.41" cy="306.74" rx="25.4" ry="5.2"/><ellipse cx="237.99" cy="173.15" rx="24.13" ry="4.94"/></g><path d="m468.56 141.66a12.5 12.5 0 0 1 -12.5 12.5h-55.69a13.57 13.57 0 0 0 -13.09 10.05l-51.21 191.11a37 37 0 0 1 -35.71 27.4h-194.59a12.49 12.49 0 0 1 -12.29-10.21 12.35 12.35 0 0 1 -.21-2.29 12.5 12.5 0 0 1 12.5-12.5h194.59a12 12 0 0 0 11.56-8.87l51.21-191.11a38.61 38.61 0 0 1 37.24-28.58h55.69a12.35 12.35 0 0 1 2.29.21 12.51 12.51 0 0 1 10.21 12.29z" fill="#c2aacf"/><path d="m458.56 131.66a12.5 12.5 0 0 1 -12.5 12.5h-55.69a13.57 13.57 0 0 0 -13.09 10.05l-51.21 191.11a37 37 0 0 1 -35.71 27.4h-194.59a12.35 12.35 0 0 1 -2.29-.21 12.35 12.35 0 0 1 -.21-2.29 12.5 12.5 0 0 1 12.5-12.5h194.59a12 12 0 0 0 11.56-8.87l51.21-191.11a38.61 38.61 0 0 1 37.24-28.58h55.69a12.35 12.35 0 0 1 2.29.21 12.35 12.35 0 0 1 .21 2.29z" fill="#decee5"/><ellipse cx="131.16" cy="365.22" fill="#f4e6f4" rx="28.4" ry="5.82"/><ellipse cx="188.99" cy="365.22" fill="#f4e6f4" rx="18.71" ry="3.83"/><path d="m459.17 132.52v16.93a11.25 11.25 0 0 1 -11.25 11.25h-39.56a11.26 11.26 0 0 1 -11.26-11.25v-16.93a11.26 11.26 0 0 1 11.26-11.26h39.56a11.26 11.26 0 0 1 11.25 11.26z" fill="#334353"/><path d="m459.17 132.52v4.26a11.26 11.26 0 0 1 -11.25 11.22h-39.56a11.26 11.26 0 0 1 -11.26-11.26v-4.26a11.26 11.26 0 0 1 11.26-11.26h39.56a11.26 11.26 0 0 1 11.25 11.3z" fill="#3e4e60"/><ellipse cx="418.41" cy="130.06" fill="#3f6c8e" rx="13.66" ry="5.23"/><ellipse cx="444.18" cy="130.06" fill="#3f6c8e" rx="9.69" ry="3.71"/></svg>
        </div>
        <form action="/search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Αναζήτησε στο mygrocery">
        </form>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h3 id="discount">Δές 5000 προσφορές για σήμερα</h3>
        <section>
            <h3>Κατηγορίες προιόντων</h3>
            <div id="category-container">
                <div class="categories" id="foods">
                    <h2>Τρόφημα</h2>
                    <p>Τυριά Αλλαντικά Delicatessen</p>
                    <p>Γαλακτοκομικά - Είδη Ψυγείου</p>
                    <p>Οπωροπωλείο</p>
                    <!-- <img src="../images/food.jpg" alt="food image"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="categories" id="drinks">
                    <h2>Κάβα</h2>
                    <p>Κρασιά</p>
                    <p>Ποτά</p>
                    <p>Αναψυκτικά</p>
                    <!-- <img src="../images/drinks.jpg" alt="food image"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="categories" id="personalCare">
                    <h2>Προσωπική Φροντιδα</h2>
                    <p>Για άνδρες</p>
                    <p>Για γυναίκες</p>
                    <p>Στοματική υγιεινή</p>
                    <!-- <img src="../images/personalCare.jpg" alt="food image"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="categories" id="babyCare">
                    <h2>Βρεφικά Είδη</h2>
                    <p>Βρεφικό Γάλα</p>
                    <p>Παιδικές Τροφές</p>
                    <p>Πάνες</p>
                    <!-- <img src="../images/babyCare.jpg" alt="food image"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="categories" id="pets">
                    <h2>Κατοικίδια</h2>
                    <p>Είδη για Σκύλους</p>
                    <p>Είδη για Γάτες</p>
                    <!-- <img src="../images/petCare.jpg" alt="food image"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="categories" id="home">
                    <h2>Όλα για το Σπίτι</h2>
                    <p>Καθαριότητα Σπιτιού</p>
                    <p>Απορρυπαντικά Πιάτων</p>
                    <p>Πλύσιμο Ρούχων</p>
]                    <!-- <img src="../images/home.jpg" alt="food image"> -->
                </div>
            </div> 
        </section>
    </main>
    <%- include("includes/footer.ejs") %>

    <script>
        function openNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "80%";
          document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
        }
        
        function closeNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
          document.body.style.position = '';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the error i recieve

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/app.js:100:20
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at IncomingMessage.next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at done (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1007:25)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:275:14)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at exports.index (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/controller/viewController.js:2:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at exports.isLoggedIn (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/controller/authController.js:221:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at hpp (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/hpp/lib/index.js:146:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/xss-clean/lib/index.js:11:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express-mongo-sanitize/index.js:79:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:110:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:72:24)
    at xXssProtection (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/x-xss-protection/dist/index.js:47:13)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:75:13)
    at nosniff (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/dont-sniff-mimetype/dist/index.js:5:9)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:75:13)
    at xDownloadOptionsMiddleware (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/middlewares/x-download-options/index.js:5:5)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:75:13)
    at hsts (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/hsts/index.js:52:5)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:75:13)
    at hidePoweredBy (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/hide-powered-by/dist/index.js:13:13)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:75:13)
    at xFrameOptionsMiddleware (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/middlewares/x-frame-options/index.js:56:9)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:75:13)
    at xDnsPrefetchControlMiddleware (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/middlewares/x-dns-prefetch-control/index.js:8:9)
    at internalNext (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:75:13)
    at helmet (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/helmet/dist/index.js:77:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at cookieParser (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:57:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/send/index.js:421:12)
    at next (/Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/send/index.js:763:28)
    at /Users/christosgoulas/Desktop/myGrocery/node_modules/send/index.js:771:23
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be yours problem. If error.e is undefined, that will throw an error

```
e: error.e.message ? error.e.message : ""
```

Change this check to

```
e: error.e && error.e.message ? error.e.message : ""
```

Or simply

```
e: error.e?.message ? error.e.message : ""
```

If nodejs version is higher than 14.0.0+

Comment: No this did not work. When the user is not logged in i set res.locals.user = " " and works fine. I suppose it is something with res.render and res.locals that causes the problem

Comment: A root error is thrown, and since error.e is not defined in app.js: 100, an environment error is thrown (in your server, not the client), because of this you cannot see the problem and debug it. You need to change this and reproduce your actions and you will see the real error.